# CSS weirdness with width transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

Made a web portfolio. Around my name there is contact data. Initial width of text is 0, when hovering the icons expand with the "transition" property. Icons on the left work fine, but those on the right have a weird transition, especially the phone.

http://jsfiddle.net/4y9eW/

```
<div class="contactbox left">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/D4NiMG" class="contactchild" id="contacttwittertext">
        <span class="contacticon-twitter"></span>
        <span class="contacttext">@D4NiMG</span>
    </a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/+DaniMu%C3%B1ozGuardiola" class="contactchild" id="contactgoogleplustext">
        <span class="contacticon-google-plus"></span>
        <span class="contacttext">+DaniMu&ntilde;ozGuardiola</span>
    </a>
</div>
<span id="titlespan">Dani Guardiola</span>
<div class="contactbox right">
    <a href="mailto:d4nimg@gmail.com" class="contactchild" id="contactemailtext">
        <span class="contacticon-email"></span>
        <span class="contacttext">d4nimg@gmail.com</span>
    </a>
    <a href="tel:+34607017025" class="contactchild" id="contactphonetext">
        <span class="contacticon-phone"></span>
        <span class="contacttext">+34 607 01 70 25</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contacttext {
    display: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.contactchild:hover .contacttext {
    display: inline-block;
}
.contactchild  {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 32px;
    color: white;
    transition: width 0.3s;
}
#contacttwittertext:hover {
    transition: width 0.3s;
    width: 107px;
    color: #00aced;
}
#contactgoogleplustext:hover {
    transition: width 0.3s;
    width: 189px;
    color: #D34836;
}
#contactemailtext:hover {
    transition: width 0.3s;
    width: 175px;
    color: #8036d3;
}
#contactphonetext:hover {
    transition: width 0.3s;
    width: 154px;
    color: #6fd336;
}
```

Comment: You mean the fact that your whole phone number appears in two lines, and the width slowly increases?

Comment: yeah, that's it, and the email text appears first (for a very short time) on the icon, rather than on the right side.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4y9eW/

Comment: Code in the question is alway prefered over a fidle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the phone is that the text wraps. Set

```
.contactchild { white-space: nowrap }
```

The weird overlap is caused by your *misuse* of position: absolute. Get rid of that. Move it around with margins, the parent forcing nowrap.

The weird underscores has to do with the spaces in the HTML. See [1](http://jsfiddle.net/qh2r5/) vs [2](http://jsfiddle.net/qh2r5/1/). It's `<a>`'s underline (note the spaces).

Comment: Alternatively one could use a set height and `overflow:hidden`, but in this case this is the best answer

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. There's an error "no-wrap" is not correct, it is "nowrap".

Comment: Another issue i'm having is on the email label, the text appears first (for a very short time) on the icon, rather than on the right side.

Comment: Thanks, overlap is not happening anymore. Now i got 2 new issues, a strange underscore shows before the labels, and i can't move them with margins. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DaniGuardiola 1. It looks like something in your HTML, that's weird 2. Your margins are moving them

Comment: @ZachSaucier What is wrong on the HTML? Sorry i don't get it. And about "2": i can move it left and right, but not up and down

Comment: @DaniGuardiola See edit. 2) Ok, `position: relative` is fine.

Comment: @bjb568 Oh! Of course! position: relative hahaha i don't know what i am thinking. Thanks. About the underline, sorry but i don't see the change in the code, can you tell me wich line is modified?